# Community Promotion Ads - 2014

Tags: discussion, community-ads

We're now at December 2013, which means that we get to see our first cycling of the Community Promotion Ads here!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- interesting reads and resources for skeptics
- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2570).

Comment: Last year, we only had one eligible upvoted advert. So, it got put on high rotation, and I got very bored of it. I'm hoping this year we will get a few more approved, just for the variety.

Comment: Is there any way to make this post a "sticky"? I had a bit of a time finding this and wanted to promote it.

Answer (score 15):

[image: Google Scholar Web Search: Stand on the shoulders of giants]

Comment: Direct copy of advert voted up in 2013.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Space Exploration Stack Exchange]

Comment: Credit: [@Undo](http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/a/366/49)

Answer (score 13):

[image: Facebook group dedicated to stopping the misinformation about vaccinations spread by the Australian Vaccination Network]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Cochrane is a non-profit organization working to produce credible, accessible health information that is free from commercial sponsorship and other conflicts of interest.]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 10):

[Current Skeptics Stack Exchange bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/skeptics.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: This is a magic image, shared by [Kyle Cronin](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1521/64236), that automatically updates based on current unanswered bounties. It breaks one of the rules, as it is not hosted by imgur, so it won't surprise me if it doesn't get put into rotation even if it gets the votes, but cool, huh?

Comment: Not entirely sure of the rules it uses - seems to exclude some featured questions. It also seems too large... (but maybe it adapts or something?)... but cool, huh?

Comment: The image is double resolution, so that it looks great when scaled down on retina devices

Comment: @KyleCronin - Any solution regarding [this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224764/187824)?

Comment: I saw this add on skeptics and it was claiming that it had an invalid referrer. [The page it was on](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4209/is-it-necessary-to-change-motor-oil-every-5-000km-3-000-miles) | [Source code on that page](https://gist.github.com/MikeHoffert/9498246) (also, it was a pain in the ass to make this comment because every time I logged in, I was redirected to the skeptics homepage and pasting the link of this page would somehow log me out)

Comment: That's odd. Looks fine to me. @KyleCronin?

Comment: @Mike Are you using a browser setting or extension that prevents referers being sent when fetching resources on another server? The ad looks for the referer to determine which SE site it's on.

Comment: @hims056 OK, I responded to that. I'll see if Nathan can make an image to handle the case where there's no bounties.

Comment: @Kyle, I figured out what the issue was. It appears that the HTTPS version of the site (enforced by the extension HTTPS Everywhere) doesn't like the ad. The ad works fine on the HTTP site (my solution was to disable HTTPS Everywhere's rule for Stack Exchange).

Comment: Also, HTTPS seems to have been the cause of my login issues. I'm guessing Stack Exchange doesn't play nicely with HTTPS at all?

Comment: @Mike The image has been updated to display a message when there are no bounties. I have also added a route where you can specify the SE site in the URL so that it doesn't need to rely on the referer: http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/skeptics.stackexchange.com/bounty.png

Answer (score 9):

[image: rbutr is a browser plugin that tells you when the webpage you are viewing has been disputed, rebutted or contradicted elsewhere on the internet.]

Comment: This is a great tool!  Skeptic Action uses this extensively.

Answer (score 9):

[image: A reference source for urban legends, folklore, myths, rumors, and misinformation.]

Comment: Let's give our Web 1.0 competitor some traffic.

Comment: I'm still upset they didn't get back to me on the [spider eating question](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/is-a-writer-named-lisa-holst-responsible-for-the-belief-that-everyone-eats-eight)...

Comment: Snopes is incidentally not a great example of sceptical inquiry. Many of their articles lack adequate references and are entirely opaque to double-checking (as Sklivvz has noticed himself). Linking to them is in many instances a pure appeal to authority, which worries me.

Comment: @Konrad: I sometimes avoid their articles that have inadequate references (or explicitly call out their weakness), but if seems to be a minority. I certainly agree that Snopes can be a false authority and their claims need to be verified, because it says so on [Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/lost/false.asp)!

Comment: @Oddthinking “Do as I say, not as I do”, clearly. Snopes is notorious for not replying to emails requesting details on sources.

Answer (score 8):

[image: WOT is a free website reputation, rating and review tool that helps find trustworthy websites and protects against online scams, untrustworthy links, and unreliable web stores. Free add-on for Firefox, IE, Chrome, Opera and Safari browsers.]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Skeptic Action]

Comment: By the way, for those interested in what this is, basically it's a confluence of WoT and rbutr.  Each day a website is highlighted on the facebook page, or the twitter account, and you are asked to evaluate it as a skeptic with WoT and to use rbutr on it.  Sometimes, pro-skeptic sites are featured too.

Answer (score 6):

[image: A large, active website for people who try to think rationally.]

Answer (score 5):

[image: The mission of the Committee for Skeptical Inquiry is to promote scientific inquiry, critical investigation, and the use of reason in examining controversial and extraordinary claims.]

Comment: Why CSI instead of CFI? I don't quite understand the relationship between the two.

Answer (score 4):

[image: The mission of the Richard Dawkins Foundation for Reason and Science is to support scientific education, critical thinking and evidence-based understanding of the natural world in the quest to overcome religious fundamentalism, superstition, intolerance and suffering.]

Comment: Dawkin's misogyny and rape culture is repugnant. Also, while I want Muslims to become non-practising or atheist, I am worried about his attitude towards Muslims. We can't condone his behaviour by promoting his foundation, especially in an ad which includes his photo. (I could have merely said that Dawkins is an embarrassment to skepticism and atheism and left it at that, but I felt I ought to give the real reason I'm downvoting it)

Comment: I agree with @AndrewGrimm not about the Muslims (all law-abiding people should be entitled to religious freedom, including Muslims, and Jews like me :O) but because that big photo of Dawkins is like tacky hero worship. In light of his not so congenial attitude toward women, alluded to by Andrew, it is extra distasteful. Any input from other women would be helpful. In general, I'd prefer not to see **anyone's** face in SE advertisements! ~>If this ad were used in 2015 sans photo, it would be a lot less obtrusive.<~

Comment: The accusations of misogyny, rape culture and xenophobia [are wrong](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/3011/82), and largely stem from a dishonest campaign against him. That said, I agree that a personal avatar – of whichever kind – has no place on an ad displayed on Skeptics.SE and that, if we want to advertise the RDF at all, we should do so in an entirely different way.

Comment: @KonradRudolph who's behind the "dishonest campaign against him"?

Comment: @Andrew I’m not sure anybody is *behind* it, I think it’s more of a mutually enforcing circle jerk: Dawkins is currently a favourite person to bash.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Arqade: Q&A for players of video games]

Comment: [Ads can go both ways, right?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5627/3610)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Chemistry - Stack Exchange]

Comment: [Stolen from Electronics.SE](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/2540/11279)

Answer (score 2):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]

Comment: Stolen from [Math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/8196/5635)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Support the Pastafarianism Proposal!]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Launceston Skeptics]